# Using deferred to force one call finishes before refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe, jquery-deferred

I have an ajax call in my JavaScript code which receives a GUID in the response from server side code. On the success method it uses that GUID to call an iframe and then after that call is done, it is supposed to refresh the page.

What I see in fiddler is that the iframe session is getting aborted. My only guess is that it is getting aborted by the browser when forced to refresh: if I remove the refresh part, the iframe session sends the request and receives the response successfully.

**How can I make the page refresh when the iframe has finished its job?** Someone suggested that I use the promise, but I tried `$.Deferred()` in jQuery and still wasn't successful. I think I am not using the `$.Deferred()` method correctly.

Note: it works if I set ajax to call in sync manner but I am hoping to find a better solution.

Here is what I have in code:

```
foo() {
   this.$link.click((e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          url: "/serverEndpoint",
          type: "POST",
          success: (id) => {
          this.iframeCall(id);
          window.location.href = window.location.origin;
          },
          error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          }
         });
    });
 }

iframeCall(id) {
   var iframe = document.createElement('IFRAME');
   iframe.setAttribute("src", someUrl+id);
   iframe.style.display = 'none';
   document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

Comment: it needs to hit server side code. Do you know how can I make the iframeCall to be a promise and have the refresh page in .then? I tried but wasn's successful

Comment: sorry I thought you are asking about the first ajax, iframe will change some state on the endpoint and needs to be an iframe call. That part I can't change

Comment: different domains

Comment: There we go, :).  Ok so you may can put an on load event handler on the iframe.  But I'm not entirely sure on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return a jQuery deferred object from `iframeCall()` when `load` event of `iframe` element is dispatched, then perform task

```
iframeCall(id) {
   return new $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
     var iframe = document.createElement('IFRAME');
     iframe.onload = dfd.resolve;
     iframe.setAttribute("src", someUrl+id);
     iframe.style.display = 'none';
     document.body.appendChild(iframe);
   })
}
```

```
this.iframeCall(id).then(function() {
  window.location.href = window.location.origin;
})
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your answer, I tried this solution the iframe works but the page doesn't refresh : window.location.href = window.location.origin;. Any point why or how to fix it?

Comment: What is `window.location.origin`?

Comment: it is the root page, basically this making the page to refresh

Comment: Then the code should return expected result. What do you mean by "doesn't refresh"?

Comment: Then the `iframe` is probably not being loaded. can you reproduce issue at plnkr https://plnkr.co?

Comment: there are a lot of code involved, i wont be able  to put all plnkr but in browser network I can see that the iframe request and response and 200 status code, I even added a alert() to .then clause and that one is not working, the iframe is working but somehow doesn't resolve the way it should

Comment: what is the dfd in your code?

Comment: The parameter passed to [jQuery.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) `beforeStart` function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158115/discussion-between-alreadylost-and-guest271314).

Comment: so what I did is that I commented all commands in iframeCall() and have this: iframeCall(id) {
   return new $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
     console.log(id)
   })
}
this.iframeCall(id).then(function() {
  window.location.href = window.location.origin; alert('test');
}) and the code still doesn't work. I think the issue is the way I am defining deferred. Also I am seeing this error when building locally  error TS2350: Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword.

Comment: That is different code than appears at code at Answer. You do not resolve or reject the jQuery promise object

Comment: No, the code is not the same, else you would get the same result as code at Answer

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bLyawt9k/